# std::map changing default order

Tags: unordered-map, stdmap

I have a text file contains settingsname , settingsvalue and UserName with tab delimited. In the text file I have more than 100 default settings. If any user changes any default setting, I will not overwrite the default setting with new setting. Instead of, I added a new record by mentioning the username. When retrieving data, Initially I am loading default settings one map container (string, string). (settingsname is key, settingsvalue is Value) Then I loading the specific user settings in a another map. And Overriding the default map with user map using the below code.

```
for(it=usrMap.begin();it!=usrMap.end();it++)
{
    defMap[it->first]=it->second;
}
```

The text file contains Data in a Specific order. Its not sorted alphabetically. While printing the default map values , I want the data in the order what I specified in a Text file. I can't keep settings name in a ordered way for some reason. How can I do this using map ?

Answer (score 0):

a std::map cannot be made stable; it will 'sort' the elements using the hashfunction. if the order is important, you can keep ordered keys in a vector (for example) and access the map in the order suggested by the vector.